# add a third party library to ext js application lazily (that is only when it is required)

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I want to add a third party js to a sencha application, lazily, only when rendering a new window, for example on clicking a button, a new window is popped up, and when this happens the d3.js library js is also loaded.

For loading a new file in Ext js itself, we can use requires key:

```
requires : ['MyApp.stores.UserStore']
```

as described in [extjs documentation](http://www.sencha.com/blog/using-ext-loader-for-your-application/). Can we do something like this for third party libraries also?

P.S. - I am using Ext Js 4.1.0

Answer (score 5):

**Update**

You should be able to load nearly anything with **Ext.Loader.[loadScript(options)](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Loader-method-loadScript)** The method also provides a callback which is called when the loading is done.

---

Basically you can load anything as long as it is a single ExtJS class per file (I must admit that I never tried anything else!). You can register additional paths using

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('EL','your/path/name'); // not done in the example below!
```

and require something at runtime is quite easy as long as the loader is configured for that. Following is a example which loads the `Ext.ux.statusbar.StatusBar` at runtime from another domain and a complete new path. Here's the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/czrt6/32/)** - just click the button and the class get loaded and after that applied with `addDocked`

```
Ext.Loader.setPath(  'Ext', 'http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/extjs-build/examples');
Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    tbar: {
      xtype: 'statusbar',
      statusAlign: 'right',
        items: [
          {
            xtype: 'button', 
            text: 'show window', 
            id: 'ani-target', 
            handler: function(btn) { 
              if (btn.up('panel').down('window').isVisible()) {
                btn.up('panel').down('window').hide();
                btn.setText('maximize');
              }else {
                btn.up('panel').down('window').show();
                btn.setText('minimize');
                Ext.define('Ext.ux.custom.StatusBar',{
                  extend: 'Ext.ux.statusbar.StatusBar',
                  alias: 'widget.cstatus',
                  requires: ['Ext.ux.statusbar.StatusBar'],
                  text: 'Ready',
                  initComponent: function() {
                    this.callParent(arguments);
                  }
                });
                btn.up('panel').down('window').addDocked({ xtype: 'cstatus'});
              } 
            }
          }
        ],
    },
  items: [{
    xtype: 'window',
    closable: false,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    id: 'demo-win',
    animateTarget: 'ani-target'
  }]
})
```

Comment: what about non EXT js like for example I need to add, [d3.js](http://d3js.org/), for a visualization for only one view.

Comment: @rubyprince I added a empty class `Ext.define('Ext.classname')` to the d3 file with the appropriate name so that the loader can load a class which satisfy him to throw no error. Now I am not familiar with d3 and cannot test if I have access to the lib. But you might try something similar.

Comment: @sra: Does this allow you to also automatically build with the loaded library later on or that's a separate issue?